# React Native TextInput has no focus method

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-textinput

I've been digging around and I can't seem to find a proper way to focus the next TextInput in a form. I'm using React Native 0.61.5 & React 16.9.0 and have set-up the project with a Typescript template. Most of what I've found online uses earlier versions of React Native or React and I can't downgrade because it's a company project and what versions we use are up to the dev leads.

React Native's documentation https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#__docusaurus doesn't show a .focus() method to exist on TextInput. There's onFocus, but that occurs after the TextInput has been focused, it doesn't help us set the focus to a particular TextInput on the screen after hitting the return key.

Using refs is a sound idea:

> inputRef = React.createRef<'TextInput>(); // (comma after < because it kept hiding the code)
>
> Intellisense for hovering over inputRef:
> (property) LoginForm.inputRef: React.RefObject<'TextInput>  // (comma after < because it kept hiding the code)

I'm using this ref like this:

> this.inputRef?.current?.focus();

but I keep getting a typescript error saying:

> Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'TextInput'.

Which, given the documentation, makes sense since I couldn't find it as a property there.

> Intellisense for TextInput when hovering over ref attribute:
> (JSX attribute) React.ClassAttributes.ref?: string | ((instance: TextInput | null) => void) | React.RefObject | null | undefined

I want to be able to tap the return key on the android/ios virtual keyboard and have the focus shift to the next TextInput so that I can submit the form.

Comment: How are you calling the focus function? Can you try this? `this.inputRef.current.focus()` - Note the `current` property

Comment: I'll edit to show how I'm calling it, I'm using this.inputRef?.current?.focus();

Comment: You may be using the wrong type for your reactRef. If you put your mouse over where you have `ref={...}` in your `TextInput`. What is the generic type shown in the intellisense?

Comment: On the TextInput I get 
React.ClassAttributes<TextInput>.ref?: string | ((instance: TextInput | null) => void) | React.RefObject<TextInput> | null | undefined

and on the inputRef I get
(property) LoginForm.inputRef: React.RefObject<TextInput>
when hovering over inputRef

Comment: I've update the code above to show what the intellisense values are

Answer (score 1):

The object create with `React.createRef()` have the following shape

```
{ current: TextInput }
```

You can access the text input element by doing:

```
inputRef.current.focus();
```

Comment: I'm accessing the ref using this.inputRef?.current?.focus();
Unfortunately I'm still getting a ts error: Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'TextInput'

Comment: Can you copy-paste the place where you instanciate the textInput?

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextInput
    placeholder = "FirstTextInput"
    returnKeyType = { "next" }
    onSubmitEditing={() => { this.secondTextInput.focus(); }}
    blurOnSubmit={false}
/>

<TextInput
    ref={input => { this.secondTextInput = input; }}
    placeholder = "secondTextInput"
/>
```

Comment: I've come across this solution before but I kept running into the error that .focus() doesn't exist on type TextInput & the docs don't show that property to exist on TextInput  either.